# Recover from task failed beyond max_retries

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am attempting to asynchronously consume a web service because it takes up to 45 seconds to return.  Unfortunately, this web service is also somewhat unreliable and can throw errors.  I have set up `django-celery` and have my tasks executing, which works fine until the task fails beyond `max_retries`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@task(default_retry_delay=5, max_retries=10)
def request(xml):
    try:
        server = Client('https://www.whatever.net/RealTimeService.asmx?wsdl')
        xml = server.service.RunRealTimeXML(
            username=settings.WS_USERNAME,
            password=settings.WS_PASSWORD,
            xml=xml
        )
    except Exception, e:
        result = Result(celery_id=request.request.id, details=e.reason, status="i")
        result.save()
        try:
            return request.retry(exc=e)
        except MaxRetriesExceededError, e:
            result = Result(celery_id=request.request.id, details="Max Retries Exceeded", status="f")
            result.save()
            raise
    result = Result(celery_id=request.request.id, details=xml, status="s")
    result.save()
    return result
```

Unfortunately, `MaxRetriesExceededError` is not being thrown by `retry()`, so I'm not sure how to handle the failure of this task.  Django has already returned HTML to the client, and I am checking the contents of `Result` via AJAX, which is never getting to a full fail `f` status.

So the question is:  How can I update my database when the Celery task has exceeded `max_retries`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can override the after_return method of the celery task class, this method is called after the execution of the task whatever is the ret status (SUCCESS,FAILED,RETRY)

```
class MyTask(celery.task.Task)

    def run(self, xml, **kwargs)
        #Your stuffs here

    def after_return(self, status, retval, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo=None):
        if self.max_retries == int(kwargs['task_retries']):
            #If max retries are equals to task retries do something
        if status == "FAILURE":
            #You can do also something if the tasks fail instead of check the retries
```

<s>http://readthedocs.org/docs/celery/en/latest/reference/celery.task.base.html#celery.task.base.BaseTask.after_return</s>

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html?highlight=after_return#celery.app.task.Task.after_return

Comment: Since the link apparently is obsolete now, [here is a new one](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html?highlight=after_return#celery.app.task.Task.after_return)

Answer (score 18):

The issue is that celery is trying to re-raise the exception you passed in when it hits the retry limit. The code for doing this re-raising is here: https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v3.1.20/celery/app/task.py#L673-L681

The simplest way around this is to just not have celery manage your exceptions at all:

```
@task(max_retries=10)
def mytask():
    try:
        do_the_thing()
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            mytask.retry()
        except MaxRetriesExceededError:
            do_something_to_handle_the_error()
            logger.exception(e)
```

Comment: This is the right solution for the original problem.

Comment: Does not work. Getting `RuntimeError: Never call result.get() within a task!`

Answer (score 15):

With Celery version 2.3.2 this approach has worked well for me:

```
class MyTask(celery.task.Task):
    abstract = True

    def after_return(self, status, retval, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        if self.max_retries == self.request.retries:
            #If max retries is equal to task retries do something

@task(base=MyTask, default_retry_delay=5, max_retries=10)
def request(xml):
    #Your stuff here
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm just going with this for now, spares me the work of subclassing Task and is easily understood.

```
# auto-retry with delay as defined below. After that, hook is disabled.
@celery.shared_task(bind=True, max_retries=5, default_retry_delay=300)
def post_data(self, hook_object_id, url, event, payload):
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    try:
        r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        if self.request.retries >= self.max_retries:
            log.warning("Auto-deactivating webhook %s for event %s", hook_object_id, event)
            Webhook.objects.filter(object_id=hook_object_id).update(active=False)
            return False
        raise self.retry(exc=e)
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you! Went with your solution. I also added `throw=False`. I've tried the other solution that uses `MaxRetriesExceededError`, and the process would get stuck at when `.join()` is called for a group of tasks.